# Existence of a type of simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I want to prove that the following proposition is false:

There exists a homologically trivial finite 2 dimensional simplicial complex $\mathcal K$ such that every edge (1 dimensional simplex) has at least 3 adjacent faces (2 dimensional simplex)

Testing with some examples I notice that if every edge has 3 adjacent faces the complex is not trivial but I do not know how to prove the proposition.

Comment: Do you require the complex to be finite/compact ?

Comment: The complex is finite

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question by completely changing it. This not only removes content from  the site, but it also negates the efforts of those who have answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the given condition implies that the number of edges $e$ is less than or equal to the number of faces $f$.

The chain $\mathbb{Z}^f\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^e\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^v$ gives trivial homology if the first map is injective and the image of the first map is the kernel of the second map. Since $e\leq f$ and the first map is injective, the image is whole $\mathbb{Z}^e$ so the second map must be the zero map. Can you see why this is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think about what you can say about the Euler characteristic of $\mathcal{K}$.

A full proof is hidden below.

> Say $\mathcal{K}$ has $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, and $F$ faces.  Consider the set $S$ of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a$ is a face and $b$ is a boundary edge of $a$.  Since every face has three boundary edges, $|S|=3F$.  But since every edge is in the boundary of at least $3$ faces, $|S|\geq 3E$.  Thus $F\geq E$.  Now the Euler characteristic of $\mathcal{K}$ is $$V-E+F\geq V.$$  Since $\mathcal{K}$ is $2$-dimensional, it has at least one face, and thus at least $3$ vertices.  So the Euler characteristic of $\mathcal{K}$ is at least $3$, and in particular greater than $1$, so the homology of $\mathcal{K}$ cannot be trivial.